# WordPress posts per page via URL GET parameters

Tags: wordpress, url, get

I want to see all the posts on my WordPress blog which are tagged with `foo`.

If I visit `https://example.com/blog/tag/foo` - it shows me the default number of pages, 10, and an option to view more at the bottom.

Is there a URL parameter I can use to show *all* to posts? Or to show 15 posts?

If I use `?order=asc` or `?order=desc` I can change the order in which they are displayed.  But if I use `?posts_per_page=100` nothing changes.

I don't want to install any plugins, or alter any code on my blog.

Comment: Does posts_per_page=-1 do anything?

Comment: Nope, sorry. `-1` doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following :

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( \WP_Query $q )
{
    if( ! is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() )
    {
        $paged = abs((int)$_GET['post_per_page']);
        if( ! empty( $paged ) && $paged >= 1 ){
            $q->set( 'posts_per_page', $paged );
        } elseif($paged === 0){
            $q->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
        }
    }
} );
```

Here you can specify a `post_per_page` URL parameter to 0 if you want all posts, or an absolute INT if you want a specific number of post.

Note that this will apply on all non-admin main queries, so you might want to restrict editing the query to the page or page type you need.

If the default Wordpress pagination (page parameter) is not working, you can add something like

`$q->set( 'paged', get_query_var( 'paged' ) ?: 1 );`

Which can be used with `?paged=2` or `/page/2` if you have proper rewriting.

Comment: Thank you, but as I said in the question, I don't want to alter any of the code on my site.

Comment: OK. It don't need any existing code edition. You just need to add this code to your function.php